# Using fstreams and stringstreams: Trouble getting a char after getting the string (C++)

Tags: c++, output, fstream, stringstream

(C++) I want to display the first part, which works fine, then the dollar sign on another line, then the price. Here's what I have:

```
string mystring;
ofstream oFile( "C:\\beer.txt" );
oFile << "Heineken#$7.99" << endl;

fstream File( "C:\\beer.txt" , ios :: in | ios :: out );
getline(File, mystring, '#');
stringstream mystringstream;
mystringstream.str(mystring);
cout << "The list contains: " << mystring << endl;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Everything above this line works just fine
// now I want to display the dollar sign

string mystring2;
getline (File, mystring2, '7');
stringstream mystringstream2;
mystringstream2.str(mystring2);
char dollar = mystring.at(mystring2.length()-1);
cout << "The tender is: " << dollar << endl ;
// this does not work

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//now, I want to display the price, in xx.xx format
//I've been looking for proper functions, but nothing works. Any help 
//is greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you never defined `mydollar`, not sure exactly what you expect there.

Comment: You should close the output file before you read it.  If you want to write and read, open it like your 2nd one, but before you write to it.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, this should display the amount:

```
string mystring2;
getline (File, mystring2);
std::cout << "Amount: " << mystring2 << endl ;
```

You have already read the part before the amount with your first getline call, so the next getline will read the rest of the string. Just print it out.

Comment: It doesn't display anything after Amount. and for some reason, the first part no longer display anything after "contains"